# In ASP.NET Core, is it possible to generate a URI in the controller for a Get action that takes two parameters? If so how?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an association controller called ConnectionManagerCategoriesController.  It has two Get methods on it. One to get all Categories for a ConnectionManager and one to only retrieve one Categoy for the ConnectionManager based upon the name. I have a Post to create a new category and I am trying to generate a uri for LinkGenerator.  However when the URI that is created, it uses the GetConnectionManagerCategories method instead of the GetConnectionManagerCategory.  I dont know why or how to do it differently.:

```
[Route("api/connectionmanagers/{connectionManagerID:int}/categories")]
[ApiController]
public class ConnectionManagerCategoriesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ConnectionManagerModel>>> GetConnectionManagerCategoriesAsync(int connectionManagerID){}

    [HttpGet("{categoryName}", Name = "GetConnectionManagerCategoryAsync")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ConnectionCategoryModel>> GetConnectionManagerCategoryAsync(int connectionManagerID, string categoryName){}

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ConnectionCategoryModel>> AddConnectionCategoryAsync(int connectionManagerID, string categoryName, [FromHeader(Name = "x-requestid")] string requestId)
    {
        var url = _linkGenerator.GetUriByRouteValues(HttpContext,
                                                                "GetConnectionManagerCategoryAsync",
                                                                values: new { connectionManagerID, categoryName = commandResult.CategoryName });

        return Created(url, commandResult);
    }
```

It returns the following uri to Swagger: 'http://localhost:6704/api/connectionmanagers/1/categories?categoryName=Almost'

However, when I log the uri in the code it is: http://localhost:6704/api/connectionmanagers/1/categories/newvalueadded

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to show how are trying to run the action, in order to get some explanations. Routing is very tricky and it is better not to try to create routes the way you are creating.

IMHO , it is always  a good idea to define the whole route, not just the part. Especially if you use Swager

```
[HttpGet("{~/api/connectionmanagers/{connectionManagerID:int}/categories/{categoryName}")]
 public async Task<ActionResult<ConnectionCategoryModel>> GetConnectionManagerCategoryAsync(int connectionManagerID, string categoryName){}
```